# System color scheme does not apply properly to parent view

Tags: swiftui

I have a picker with "Light", "Dark" and "System" choices. Each triggers a color scheme. The "System" triggers the system default scheme, however, it skips the parent view of AppearanceAndReadingSettingsView. And when I switch from "Light" to "System", the whole app switches to light mode without the parent view which is in a sheet.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppearanceAndReadingSettingsView: View {
    @AppStorage("appearanceMode") var appearanceMode = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker("Theme", selection: $appearanceMode) {
                Text("Light")
                    .tag(0)
                Text("Dark")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("System")
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                ClosingSheetButton()
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(appearanceMode == 0 ? .light : appearanceMode == 1 ? .dark : .none )
    }
}
```

I have tried adding @AppStorage and .preferredColorScheme to the parent view as well, but that did nothing.

Comment: All works well in my simple tests, however
show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 , show enough context to replicate the problem.

Comment: Tried with a simple picker - the same thing happens.

Comment: Note, according to the docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/preferredcolorscheme(_:)
  and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/colorscheme  there is no `.none` ColorScheme.
 It is either `light` or `dark` as given by: `ColorScheme.allCases`. You could use `@Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme` to detect the current colorScheme
 and use that, for your `system` option.